# windows API's to get the RAM information

Tags: linux, windows, memory-management

Is there any API's in windows, to get the RAM memory info like...Total RAM, Available RAM , shared RAM, buffered RAM, total swap space size)

I have checked in msdn meorymangement API's, but couldn't find much info.

Can anyone guide me on this.

Comment: What's the point of tagging `linux`?

Comment: sorry by mistake....actually this is the application which porting fro Linux to Windows.so the same data structure available in Linux (sysinfo structure) need to be filled in Windows as well

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get available RAM on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63391433/how-to-get-available-ram-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

The [`GlobalMemoryStatusEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366589.aspx) function provides high-level information of that kind. See the documentation for the [`MEMORYSTATUSEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366770.aspx) structure for a description of what is reported.

Comment: We can get the Total and Available Memory info, what about shared RAM and Buffred RAM info?

Comment: @user2713021: I don't believe such information is available. Note that the man page for `sysinfo` clearly states *"This function is Linux-specific, and should not be used in programs intended to be portable."*; since you are not following this suggestion, some turbulence is to be expected.