# How to get available RAM on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows

I am looking for method that return available RAM and for this moment I have found only this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2513561/5709159

```
#include <windows.h>

unsigned long long getTotalSystemMemory()
{
    MEMORYSTATUSEX status;
    status.dwLength = sizeof(status);
    GlobalMemoryStatusEx(&status);
    return status.ullTotalPhys;
}
```

But this method return Total memory. So, I need to find out how to get RAM that currently in usage or method than directly return available RAM.

How to do it?

**EDIT**

I need to know amount of available RAM in order to present it on my statistic form. I have a field `Available RAM :`

Comment: Like: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/ns-sysinfoapi-memorystatusex says  dwMemoryLoad gives you approx. percantage of used physical memory. With that information you could calculate the needed value. Or better do what @adrian mole answered. :)

Comment: @DevSolar added to question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the same call to `GlobalMemoryStatusEx()` and examine the `.ullAvailPhys` field of the [MEMORYSTATUSEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/ns-sysinfoapi-memorystatusex) structure to get the amount of available physical memory. The difference between this and the `.ullTotalPhys` value will be how much physical memory is in use.